# Ember-Data: Metadata does not immediately refresh with new server response?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

*Edited: I changed a few things to see if it would fix.. but no luck*

**Situation:**

I have a parent route that displays a list of accounts.  The list is paginated server-side, which I use `refresh()` to send new queries to the server...

```
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('account', { page_size: this.page_size, page_number: this.page_number });
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('meta', this.store.metadataFor('account'));
}
```

The parent route renders an outlet with a child route that shows a single account, via dynamic segment.

**The Problem:**

when the route is first entered, the metadata shows the correct values. However, when model hook re-fires, the model itself gets updated with the new server response, but the metadata does not update! It stays at its initial values.

This is counter-intuitive, as I thought the whole point of metadata was to allow for server-side pagination?

**Possible Cause?**

Frustrations aside, I have a feeling that perhaps I have created the problem, but don't know how to fix or work around.

I have one endpoint that returns a list of accounts, and I have a separate endpoint that returns a single account.  Because both endpoints return JSON with all the same fields defining an account, I have them sharing the same model class.  The difference however is that the "single account" endpoint does not return pagination data in its response, while the "list" endpoint does.

I don't know if that is the cause of the conflict or not, but i would not know how to fix it if it were.

The other possibility is that it is an elusive bug?

Please let me know if anyone else has encountered this issue or if i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define meta as a computed property on the controller:

```
meta: Ember.computed('model.isFulffiled', function() {
    return this.store.metadataFor('foo')
})
```

That should get you working.